# App crashes on reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

*** I got it figured out thanks to  Paulw11 and sjeohp comments. I was using the amount of text to change the cell height and didnt correct the objectAtIndex in that method when i changed to using the array over static text. ***

I have a chat app that im trying to use a tableView to show the chat interaction. Im saving the "source" and the contents into an array and trying to get the tableview to reload that anytime a message is sent or received but it crashes everytime on the reloadData call.

In the ViewDidLoad:

```
chatLog = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

and then other methods:

```
-(IBAction)sendMessagePressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    NSLog(@"Send Pressed");

    // if the message bar isnt blank send the message
    if ( ![messageInputBar.text isEqualToString:@""] ) {

        NSString* text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Wrote:\n%@", messageInputBar.text];

        NSString* source = @"self";

        NSArray* sent = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:source, text, nil];

        messageInputBar.text = @"";

        [self CloseMessageKeys];



        [chatLog addObject:sent];


        // this is where it crashes. this code was working with static text before
        // i implemented the mutable array
        [chatTable reloadData]; 


        NSData* messageData = [messageInputBar.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSArray* connectedPeers = _app_Delegate.mpc_Handler.mpc_session.connectedPeers;

        NSError* error;

        [_app_Delegate.mpc_Handler.mpc_session sendData:messageData toPeers:connectedPeers withMode:MCSessionSendDataReliable error:&error];

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }


    }

}
```

This is the TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ( [[[chatLog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:0]isEqualToString:@"self"]) {


        OutgoingTableViewCell* cell = [chatTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"outgoingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSString* text = [[chatLog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:1];

        cell.txtLabel.text = text;

        [[cell txtLabel] setNumberOfLines:0]; // unlimited number of lines

        [[cell txtLabel] setLineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        [[cell txtLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0]];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        [self showTheBottom];

        return cell;

    } else {

        IncomingTableViewCell* cell = [chatTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"incomingCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSString* text = [[chatLog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:1];

        cell.txtLabel.text = text;

        [[cell txtLabel] setNumberOfLines:0]; // unlimited number of lines

        [[cell txtLabel] setLineBreakMode: NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        [[cell txtLabel] setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize: 14.0]];

        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        [self showTheBottom];

        return cell;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the exception message and which line does it crash on?

Comment: -[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbeb3770

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbeb3770'

Comment: im not sure how to tell what line it crashed on, im fairly new to xcode and obj-c

Comment: I guess somewhere else in your code, probably numberOfRowsInSection, you are calling [array length].  You need to use [array count].  Also the line it crashed on should be highlighted in green when it crashes.

Comment: I think @sjeohp is right, but for general information on solving crashes - read this - http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 In particular, in this case set an exception breakpoint

Comment: Yes, Thanks @Paulw11 and sjeohp for having me look into finding the exact line causing the crash.

Comment: I am glad that you found the problem.  You should also accept one of the answers if it helped you.

Comment: if you submit an answer thats says to uses the exception breakpoint feature to find the error, ill accept that. Neither of the answers shown are the real answer.

Comment: @Paulw11 Good call directing OP to a useful resource.

Comment: @MKD_FS you can answer your own question - the cause was incorrect use of length on an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

length is not a method on NSArray. Use [array count]

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out thanks to @Paulw11 and @sjeohp comments. I was using the amount of text to change the cell height and didnt correct the objectAtIndex in that method when i changed to using the array over static text. *

in another method I had:

```
 NSAttributedString *aString = [NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[chatLog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and it needed to be:

```
 NSAttributedString *aString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[[chatLog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:1]];
```

Thanks to @Paulw11 and @sjeohp for helping me figure out the exception breakpoint feature in Xcode

Answer (score -1):

Your dequeueReusableCell code is fail. you need check if it nil then init cell. And check about numberOfRowsInSection code to return chatLog.count

Comment: In this case they are using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: As long as a nib or class was properly registered, this method will always return a valid cell. You only need to check for nil with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: